# is verifying a JWT efficient for being used in middleware?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I have an node-react project, I need to know the state of the incoming request therefore I put a middleware before any routes. I want to know what is the complexity of `.verify`
because in server-side I have a middleware which **will be hit in every request** comes to server. this is the middleware :

```
const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');
module.exports = ('/', (req,res,next)=>{ 

    if(req.cookies){
        if(req.cookies.token){
            let decoded = '' ; 
            try{
                decoded = jsonwebtoken.verify(req.cookies.token, 'this is the secret');
                req.user = decoded ; 
                req.isTokenValid = true ; 
            }catch(err){
                console.log('we got error, verifying the jwt:::', err);
                req.hasToken = true ; 
                req.isTokenValid = false ;
            }
        }
        else{
            req.hasToken = false ;
            req.isTokenValid = false ; 
        }

    }
    else{
        console.log('else for nothing in cookies');
        req.hasToken = false;  
        req.hasValidToken = false ;  
    }
    next();
})
```

as you can see in every request I am going to verify the token which is a synchronous method.

Here's the question, is this approach good and efficient ? or maybe I should put this code in a specific path instead of being a middleware? or something else ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the purpose of middleware, to be reusable. Make sure to include it on any routes that you want to have a verified token.

While you can put your verify method in an `app.use` so it can verify all routes. You would still want to have login/password reset routes declared before your auth route. Otherwise, it'll be hard for a user to login or reset a forgotten password :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, however I didn't understand this section of your answer: ou would still want to have login/password reset routes declared before your auth route. Otherwise, it'll be hard for a user to login or reset a forgotten password
because I don't save passwords inside of jwts.

Comment: `app.post('/login', etc)` & `app.post('/paswordReset', etc)` before `app.use(checkToken)` middleware then you can put all your `app.get('/protectedRoutes, etc)` afterwards